# Is there any difference between '=' and '==' operators in bash or sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operators

I realized that both '=' and '==' operators works in if statement. For example:

```
var="some string"
if [ "$var" == "some string" ];then
    #doing something
fi

if [ "$var" = "some string" ];then
    #doing something
fi
```

Both if statement above worked well in bash and sh. I just wondered if there is any difference between them? Thanks...

Comment: Your code will even work in C (leaving aside that string assignment works differently in C), and in C they are definitely different operators.

Comment: thanks, but I knew that.

Comment: Nothing else about that code is legal C syntax, so C is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside single brackets for condition test (i.e. [ ... ]), single = is supported by all shells, where as == is not supported by some of the older shells.

Inside double brackets for condition test (i.e. [[ ... ]]), there is no difference in old or new shells.

Edit: I should also note that: Always use double brackets [[ ... ]] if possible, because it is safer than single brackets. I'll illustrate why with the following example:

```
if [ $var == "hello" ]; then
```

if $var happens to be null / empty, then this is what the script sees:

```
if [ == "hello" ]; then
```

which will break your script. The solution is to either use double brackets, or always remember to put quotes around your variables ("$var"). Double brackets is better defensive coding practice.

Comment: Or, as I would see it, always use single brackets because they're more portable. Two ways to skin every cat!

Answer (score 1):

They're different in arithmetic evaluation

Within double parentheses, `=` cannot be used for comparison whereas `==` works fine, e.g.

`(( $var == 3 ))` works fine

`(( $var = 3 ))` gives error (comparison).

`(( var = 3 ))` works (assignment), but this always evaluates to TRUE

Comment: NO. It didn't act like assignment in my example. When I wrote another string ( which is not equal $var ) to check, it didn't pass inside of if. Your example will give error because == and = are for string comparison not integer.

Comment: Ok have to clear my thoughts. It doesn't work as assignment if you are using `$var = 3` since that's not a valid assignment syntax hence the error. `var = 3` would work as assignment. You are correct about `==` being string comparison though, even within `(( ))`.

Comment: No, operations in `(( ))` are strictly numeric. For example, `(( 3 == 03 ))` evaluates to true (both sides are numerically the same); so does `(( wibble == boo ))` (because neither string contains any digits, so they're both numerically zero). `(( wibble = boo ))`, on the other hand, sets the variable `wibble` to the value 0.

Comment: Ok, didn't know `(( wibble == boo ))` would work this way. I was only checking `(( wibble == wibble ))` which returned true so I incorrectly assumed `==` was doing a string comparison.

Comment: Actually, I need to correct my earlier comment: inside `(( ))`, wibble and boo aren't zero because they lack digits, but because they're treated as variable references and neither (at least when I tested) happened to be assigned. Thus, `(( wibble == boo99 ))` is true, but `boo=5; (( wibble == boo ))` comes out as false.

Comment: Yes, it seems you don't need `$` to expand variables when you're within `(( ))` or when you're using `let`