# Bash script that asks for password to view passwords file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that asks for password when you try to see the password file, but I'm stucked. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read Password
echo -n Password:  
read -s PASSWORD

passwords() {

echo "
PASSWORDS
"

}

if [ "$PASSWORD"="root" ]; then
    passwords
    exit
else
    echo "Wrong password"
    exit 

fi
```

I've tried a lot of things, for example `if [ "$PASSWORD"!="root" ]` instead of `else` but none of them worked.

Comment: What if you add a space around the equal sign, e.g. `[ "$PASSWORD" = "root" ]`

Comment: Also, it is a huge security flaw to put the password in the script like this. By definition, everyone running the script can read it (otherwise they wouldn’t be able to execute it) which means anyone can just open the script and look for the password string in plain text.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I didn't know about this, I'm very new to bash scripting

Comment: I know, I'm working with that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

passwords(){
    echo "PASSWORDS"
}

## Read Password
read -p "Enter password: " -s PASSWORD

desired_password="root"

[ "$PASSWORD" == "$desired_password" ] && passwords || echo "Wrong password"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @vdavid said, you can add a space around the equal sign or even better, as you have bash shell, it is recommended to use double-bracket for your if statement. Check this: [Is there any difference between '=' and '==' operators in bash or sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948456/is-there-any-difference-between-and-operators-in-bash-or-sh)

Also you can add:

- `printf "/n"` so your script will behave like a typical Linux prompt for password - information will output in new line
- non-zero exit code in case of wrong password (`exit 1`)

Basically, after those improvements code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read Password
echo -n Password:
read -s PASSWORD
printf "\n"

passwords() {
 echo "PASSWORDS"
}

if [[ "$PASSWORD" == "root" ]]; then
    passwords
    exit 0
else
    echo "Wrong password"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note that I used "==" instead of "=", but for double-bracket they both do the same job.